# Can spaces at the beginning of a line ever cause problems?

Tags: macros, symbols, syntax, sourcecode

To structure my sourcecode, I often use spaces for padding:

```
\newcommand{\st}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \emph{Student} & \emph{Score}\\
    #1
  \end{tabular}%
}
```

Can this ever cause problems? [Like putting no `%` at the end some lines.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/1236)

Comment: Spaces at the beginning of a line are irrelevant to TeX? You can put as many as you want.

Comment: Except in verbatim like context spaces at start of line are ignored, but note you have  missing `%` on lines 1 and 5 which could produce anomalous white space in the result.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, good call on the missing `%` :-). Someone add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Johannes_B you were first:-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually, spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored by TeX. However, this is not the case when writing in a verbatim like context. Tabulators at the beginning of a line are ignored as well.

[Whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) like `NO-BREAK SPACE` `(U+00A0)` behave in a different way. To use them properly, a modern engine like LuaLaTeX in conjunction with [fontspec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) is needed.

Please be aware, that the end of a line is nothing more than a `␣`  (space) for LaTeX, if in *M*-mode (middle of a line), so you have to be careful in the definition of your own commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\testa{h
    ello}
\newcommand\testb{h%
     ello}
\begin{document}
\testa \par \testb

\begin{verbatim}
  h
 a
   ll
o
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the same apply for tabs or other [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)?

Comment: @ComFreek Good question, I added the information to the answer. Can somebody please varify the behaviour for »other whitespace character«? I somehow would have guessed a different behaviour.

Comment: I'm not really sure about `U+00A0`, which in the normal setting of LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX has category code 12 when `fontspec` is loaded.

Comment: @egreg I tried it out myself, but as I said, i don't think this should happen. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Johannes_B Try loading `fontspec`

Comment: Thanks @egreg for pointing me in the right direction. I made the according changes.

Comment: @Johannes_B "the end of a line is nothing more than a space" — This is not entirely correct. It depends on which state TeX currently is in. If TeX is in state *N* (new line) then the end-of-line is converted to \setminuspar\nonumber whereas if TeX is in state *M* (mid-line) the end-of-line is converted to a space.

Comment: @HenriMenke I am going to add something tomorrow. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 5):

The comment environment (comment package) should start in a new line without a space before. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf):

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own.
>   No starting spaces, nothing after it.

Otherwise it won't work and cause strange errors.

Comment: the same is true for `\end{verbatim}`