# Compilation fails in beamer class with newenvironment defining nested blocks

Tags: beamer, environments

I'm failing to understand why this code compiles :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{yyy}{\begin{frame} \begin{block}{youpi}  }{\end{block} \end{frame}}
\begin{document}
 { \begin{frame} \begin{block}{youpi}   bonjour \end{block} \end{frame} }
\end{document}
```

while that one does not :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{yyy}{\begin{frame} \begin{block}{youpi}  }{\end{block} \end{frame}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{yyy}    bonjour \end{yyy}
\end{document}
```

... resulting in

```
File ended while scanning use of \beamer@collect@@body
```

If anyone has got an idea, i'd be greatful!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. Can you extend your code into a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? That would help a lot.

Comment: @Johannes_B The top example compiled fine for me.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, the minimal example is so minimal that i thought it was just a snippet. Sorry @skorqa and well done ;-)

Comment: @JohnWickerson: It compiles fine for me too

Comment: Have a look at [Can spaces at the beginning of a line ever cause problems?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147230) please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by-design and it depends on how frames are read by beamer. See [this](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/48) bug on the Beamer github repo, closed as wontfix.

You can however workaround the issue by including your code into a macro (not a new environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\yyy}[1]{
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}{youpi}
        #1
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
  \yyy{bonjour}
\end{document}
```