# Ignore whitespace during macro-definition?

Tags: macros, white-space

Does LaTeX contain a supported construct for ignoring whitespace during macro definitions?

### The default situation

By default, whitespace inside macro definitions is preserved just like everywhere else. As a consequence, any whitespace used for code structuring (primarily line breaks) must be commented out. An exception are lines ending with a `\commandToken`, as whitespace after these is ignored.

E.g. in `example_a.tex` below, in the macro definition without comments I obtain an output

```
[[ world. ComQuo.everyone! ]]
```

while with comments the desired output

```
[[world.ComQuo.everyone!]]
```

is obtained, at the cost of increased editing effort and reduced readability.

### exampla_a.tex

[image: exampla_a.pdf]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape,scale=0.9]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\hello[1]{#1}

\newcommand\CommandsQuoteSubsequentWhitespace{ComQuo.}

\newcommand\MyMacroSpaces{
  \hello{world}.
  \CommandsQuoteSubsequentWhitespace
  \hello{everyone}!
}

\newcommand\MyMacroComments{%
  \hello{world}.%
  \CommandsQuoteSubsequentWhitespace%
  \hello{everyone}!%
}

\ttfamily

SPC[[\MyMacroSpaces]] (space wanted before)

CMT[[\MyMacroComments]] (space wanted before)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in strongly related question “[It's safe to ignore tabs and newlines when defining a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241882/34769)”, the most important change (i.e. ignoring line-breaks and subsequent indentation whitespace) can be obtained by using `\endlinechar=-1` to supress line-break and subsequent whitespace. However, it needs to be reset afterwards, leading to a construct

```
\endlinechar=-1 % line-break and subsequent whitespace produce nothing
(... MACRO DEFINITIONS ...)
\endlinechar=13 %
```

with which the example document gives the output

```
SPC[[world.ComQuo.everyone!]] (space wanted before)
CMT[[world.ComQuo.everyone!]] (space wanted before)
```

### Caveats

As mentioned in the other question:

- Be careful to reset `\endlinechar` *before* other people's code is executed (e.g. `\usepackage`).
- Ignoring the line-break whitespace can have unintended consequences with some constructs, where the whitespace is needed as delimiter (see [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241882/34769)), but in those cases using a comment or explicit `\space` helps.