# Should I remove spaces at the beginning of a line containing only a footnote?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, chktex

I've just stumbled upon [`chktex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chktex?lang=en), the LaTeX lint. While using it, I've noticed that it keeps giving warnings about needing to remove spaces at the beginning of lines containing only `\footnote{Some footnote text}`. Nothing in, e.g., [this question on spaces at the beginning of lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147215/can-spaces-at-the-beginning-of-a-line-ever-cause-problems) suggests that this should be problematic, but is it?

Why does chktex complain about spaces at the beginning of a line containing a footnote?

The most minimal of MWEs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \footnote{Some footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

The `chktex` warning:

> % chktex chktexmwe.tex
>   ChkTeX v1.7.2 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T.
>   Berger Thielemann. Compiled with POSIX extended regex support. Warning
>   42 in chktexmwe.tex line 4: You should remove spaces in front of
>   `\footnote'
>           \footnote{Some footnote text.}
>          ^ chktex: WARNING -- ChkTeX does not handle lines over 1024 bytes correctly.  Some errors and line numbers may be wrong in this
>   file. No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed
>   warnings; No line suppressed warnings

Comment: Can you show a short example where `chktex` complains about space at the beginning of a line containing only a `\footnote`? I would be more inclined to complain about a line containing only one footnote than about space preceding it ....

Comment: @moewe Super minimal MWE and text of the warning that `chktex` generates added to the answer.

Comment: Er..."question" not "answer".

Comment: I think this is because generally spaces before footnotes are not desirable, `Lorem \footnote{ipsum}` (with a space) gives horrible output. ChkTeX warns you about that, but it does not detect the case at the beginning of a line, where the spaces are ignored. Note though that if you write something like `Lorem`<linebreak> `\footnote{ipsum}` you will get a space regardless of the indentation of `\footnote{ipsum}`, this can only be suppressed with a `%`, as in `Lorem%`<linebreak> `\footnote{ipsum}`. Generally I would advise against `\footnote` commands at the beginning of lines.

Comment: There are some document styles where footnotes always precede the text they refer to, and so are always preceded by white space. You see that in many English-language bibles, for example. FWIW my personal preference for formatting of the input text for footnotes is `Some text\footnote` on one line, and `{the footnote text}` indented (using a tab or spaces) on the following line, or lines. I find this easier to read, especially if there are many footnotes interrupting the "flow" of the main text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem, but only in certain instances. Consider the following minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{abc} with a footnote. \par
Some text \footnote{def} with a footnote. \par
Some text
\footnote{ghi} with a footnote. \par
Some text
  \footnote{jkl} with a footnote.
\end{document}
```

The `\footnote` with a preceding space (2, 3 and 4) is obviously incorrect. [`chktex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chktex) picks up on this in a very crude or generic way and may miss it on occasion where it should also be avoided (3).

Best would be to use it appropriately the first time around. Strategic [placement of `%` at the end of a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) could avoid spacing problem (even though it might still be picked up by `chktex`). For example,

```
Some text%
\footnote{ghi} with a footnote. \par
Some text%
  \footnote{jkl} with a footnote.
```

provides appropriate spacing around the `\footnote` (for 3 and 4 above), but `chktex` will still complain about spacing for (4).

Comment: Maybe you could add that if one insists on a line break before a `\footnote` for some reason, one can salvage the situation by putting a `%` at the end of the preceding line. In which case 3+`%` and 4+`%` do the same and look right again.

Comment: @moewe: Done...